# I am in Owners group, but I have no permission to add users to group (SP 2007)

Tags: 2007, groups

I am one of two owners of a team site that I manage. I have created several sub-sites and two groups.

One of these groups is called Trainers Team, to which I initially added 7 members. I now need to add a new member, but I am getting the error, "You do not have permission to add users to the selected SharePoint group."

If I click the link that says, "View permissions this group has on sites, lists, ..." I get a message that says, "You do not have permission to view the permission assignments for the SP group. Only the owner of the group, a member of the group, or the site collection administrator can view the permission assignments for this group."

How can I not be the owner of the group if I created it, and how could I have added the original 7 members and not be able to add another member?

Can someone please help me figure out how to add the new member to the group, rather than just giving them permission directly?

Comment: I do belive im the SP they are referring too, how do i find out what is going on with all of these thing. I know ive been copy written alot because of the notice left behind and on some phones i have 300 or more software programs they have used
On me how do i find out where and why that is??

Answer (score 1):

Also, in the Group Settings (go to the group > Settings drop-down > Group Settings), make sure you or a group you are in is listed as the "Group Owner".

[image: Group Owner in Group Settings]

Comment: Thank you, Nicole. In the Settings drop-down I see only 2 choices: Edit Group Quick Launch and Set Up Groups. If I click Set Up Groups, I see that Owners of this Site have Full Control, and those rights are assigned to the group called Trainers Team Owners. I am one of the two owners, so how could I not have permission to add users to the group? So frustrating!

Comment: @NormaMiller That's actually not the right place to look. When you're on that page, click the name of the group you want to add members to, then look at the Settings drop-down and click Group Settings. If you don't see Group Settings, then you aren't listed as an "owner". Unfortunately, even if you have full control on the site, you won't necessarily have access to everything. If that's the case, you will have to ask someone with Site Collection Administrator rights (higher than full control) to add you or a group you're in to the Group Settings.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a group there is an option to specify who can view and who can modify the group members. I strongly believe that your account might have removed from these two places.

You can contact your Site Collection Administrator and ask him to make you the owner to that particular group.

Comment: Thank you, Amal. Oh, if only I could! (Please see previous responses that I posted today.)

Answer (score 0):

You said you are the owner of the Site Colletion, right? If you are Site collection admin / Owner then you can view the permissions or add the users.

- Make Sure you are Site collection administrator.
- As the Site Collection Admin you can change Group Settings...select the group and select Settings > Group Settings to access it.[image]

Comment: Being a Site Collection Administrator Owner, Norma wouldn't have received the error. However, being a member of Site Owners group, she won't be able to edit membership of groups where she is not the group's owner whether directly or via group that owns the one being edited.

Comment: Thank you, Waqas. I don't own the site collection, and nobody around here seems to know who that person is (actually, I think it's the person who implemented SP 2007 years ago, and who has since left the company).

Comment: You can check from Central admin, who is site collection admin

Comment: Right. Actually, anyone who sees *Site Collection Administration* under your `/sites/trainers/_layouts/settings.aspx` is a Site Collection Administrator

Comment: Can I use SP Designer 2007 to somehow identify the person who can help me?

Comment: do you have access to central admin site? then it is really easy, just add yourself as site collection admin

Comment: If the implementor left the company, does it mean that nobody's taking care of the servers? Maybe you still have some admin guy who can log on to the server's console as Administrator and perform a commandline operation?

Answer (score 0):

Only Site Collection Administrator can edit memberships of **all** groups.

Some groups may be configured to only allow the group's owner (single person or SharePoint Group) to edit the membership. By default, the Visitors, Members and Owners groups are owned by the Owners group, but the groups created later manually are owned by default by the user who created them, so only that user or Site Collection Administrator can help you in this case.

Also, group owner could be changed later on.

Your email server administrators can find out who receives the quota notifications when the site's storage footprint approaches the preset limit (if any). The recipients would be the Site Collection Administrators.

You can be made a primary or secondary owner of the sitecollection by using this `stsadm` command: `stsadm -o siteowner -url http://your_server/sites/trainers -ownerlogin your_domain\norma.miller`

Comment: Thank you, Alexey. Since SP is telling me I don't have permission to view the permission assignments for the group, I'm kind of stuck! I'm an owner of the site but evidently not of the group I created in that site, and I can't determine who IS an owner of the group. It's a trap!

Comment: Apparently, you're a member of the Owners group, not a Site Collection Admin, of which the first is the Primary Site Collection Owner specified when the site collection is created.

Comment: Do you have a contact of your Farm Administrators?

Comment: I don't know who that might be. Can I use SP Designer 2007 to somehow identify the person who can help me?

Comment: Try to find the server admin guy, who can understand which server hosts SharePoint, log on, provide access, and find out the state of the matter with SharePoint support.